# Saving data to use in multiple activities

Tags: java, android, string, class, generics

I want to create an app that starts up and has five EditText boxes to input five lessons. I then want to save these 5 EditText boxes in one place to then access from all activities when needed, eg. for setting TextViews. How would I create this single set of the five strings, would they be saved in their own class?

Comment: So, save the data from the "boxes" somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you can achieve that, some of which are:

1. Use SharedPrefrences
2. Use Sqlite database - a bit more complex solution.
3. Extend the application class which is available to all activities.